# How to get body content in a http client call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am unable to get body content in this http client call, because I can't figure out how to get the actual content of the request in this async method.

**Here's the async method:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var requestUri = new Uri($"{_authorityBaseUrl}/{_tenantID}/oauth2/token");
            var authenticationBody = CreatePasswordGrantConsent(username,password);
            return await client.PostAsync(requestUri, authenticationBody);
        }
```

**Here's the method that I wanna get the body content from**

```
protected void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         AADConnector connector = new AADConnector();
         var result = connector.AuthenticateUser("username", "password").Result.Content;
    }
```

**I've tried in AuthenticateUser method to change to :**

```
public async Task<string>(string username , string password)
{
...
...
var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, authenticationBody);
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

return contents;
}
```

**And change in loginBtn_Click to :**

```
AADConnector connector = new AADConnector();
Task<string> result = connector.AuthenticateUser("username","password");
var finalResult = result.Result;
```

But it just *deadlocks* and it keeps running forever.

Can you guys explain me why this happens?

Comment: Make the `loginBtn_Click` handler async and `var finalResult = await connector.AuthenticateUser("username","password");` -- You should declare and initialize the HttpClient object as a static Field (`static Lazy<HttpClient>` is better, but the initialization is quite different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
public async Task<string> AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var requestUri = new Uri($"{_authorityBaseUrl}/{_tenantID}/oauth2/token");
    var authenticationBody = CreatePasswordGrantConsent(username, password);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, authenticationBody);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return result;
}
```

```
AADConnector connector = new AADConnector();
var result = Task.Run(async () => await connector.AuthenticateUser("username", "password"));

try {
  result.Wait();
} catch {

}

dynamic data = JObject.Parse(result.Result);
string token = (string)data.access_token;
```